# xxxxxx is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is

Tags: windows, winforms, c#-4.0, oledbconnection

I have windows application that can access files from setting.ini file I modified it and get access to them from my code. but still getting this error like `'C:\Users\infinity\Desktop\aadinathfiles\ALL EVENT FILE FORMAT\TRADING MASTER FILE\ISE CLEINT MASTER.xls' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.`

here is my setting.ini file code :

```
[UserDetail]
UserID=xxxxxxx
PassWord=xxxxxxxx

[Connection]
contact=C:\Users\infinity\Desktop\aadinathfiles\ALL EVENT FILE FORMAT\TRADING MASTER FILE\ISE CLEINT MASTER.xls
DebitISE=C:\Users\infinity\Desktop\aadinathfiles\ALL EVENT FILE FORMAT\TRADING MASTER FILE\ISE 1.xls
DebitLKP=C:\Users\infinity\Desktop\aadinathfiles\ALL EVENT FILE FORMAT\TRADING MASTER FILE\ISE CLEINT MASTER.xls

[FilePath]
DebitISEClient=C:

[FileName]
DebitISEClient=Contact_06-07-2015.txt
```

and here my code for accessing this files from ini file :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string filepath = txtpayoutfile.Text;

            string message = "";
            string mobileno = "";
            string name = "";
            DataSet dsmaster = new DataSet();
            string filepathc = ini.IniReadValue("Connection", "contact");
            if (filepath == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Import Contact File");

                this.Show();
            }
            if (Path.GetExtension(filepath) == ".xls")
            {
                oledbConn1 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filepathc + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"");
            }
            else if (Path.GetExtension(filepath) == ".xlsx")
            {
                oledbConn1 = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepathc + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");
            }

            oledbConn1.Open(); ////exception occurs here


            if (Path.GetExtension(filepath) == ".xls")
            {
                oledbConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"");
            }
            else if (Path.GetExtension(filepath) == ".xlsx")
            {
                oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");
            }

            OleDbCommand cmdoledb = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Sheet1$3:3000]", oledbConn);
            OleDbDataAdapter daoledb = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdoledb);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            daoledb.Fill(dt);
}
```

Comment: Is this simply caused by the misspelling of "client" in `ISE CLEINT MASTER.xls`?

Comment: Path containing spaces like this should be enclosed in double quotes. As a note, `ACE.OLEDB.12` ( or`ACE.OLEDB.16`) can read `.xls` files, so you don't actually need two providers.

Comment: @lan there is no spell error given path and actual file have same spell...